# Oracle SQL TOAD - Update Year in a variable ( Concat string + Year ) depending of Sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, date, concatenation

I would like to Update Year in a variable  ( string + Year ) depending of Sysdate

I want to execute a 'select' command more or less like that :

If `sysdate` is between **1st of October** and **31 December**

```
select * from table where table.date between CONCAT
('1/10/','Variable_Year_Current' )AND CONCAT
('30/09/','Variable_Year+1')
```

Else if `sysdate` is between **1 January** and **30 of September**

```
select * from table
where table.date 
between CONCAT ('1/10/','Variable_Year-1' )
AND CONCAT ('30/09/','Variable_Year_Current')
```

Comment: Conditional logic in sql commands is normally done with a case construct.

Comment: What is the data type of column `date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query worked for test data:

```
with 
  a as (select 1970 var, to_char(sysdate, 'mm-dd') today from dual),
  b as (select case when today between '10-01' and '12-31' 
                    then to_date(var  ||'-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    else to_date(var-1||'-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') end d1,
               case when today between '10-01' and '12-31' 
                    then to_date(var+1||'-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    else to_date(var  ||'-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') end d2
           from a)
select test.* from b, test 
  where tdate between b.d1 and b.d2
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82f5a/1)

In first line change 1970 to 'variable' year.

---

> '2015 var' must not be defined bymyself. 'Year var' should be defined by sysdate.

It was not quite clear what you mean as variable. You can use `extract(year from sysdate)` for this:

```
with 
  a as (select extract(year from sysdate) var, 
               to_char(sysdate, 'mm-dd') today from dual),
  b as (select case when today between '10-01' and '12-31' 
                    then to_date(var  ||'-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    else to_date(var-1||'-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') end d1,
               case when today between '10-01' and '12-31' 
                    then to_date(var+1||'-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    else to_date(var  ||'-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') end d2
           from a)
select test.* from b, test 
  where tdate between b.d1 and b.d2
```

The [WITH clause](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) is so called subquery-factoring, 
I often use it to make steps more readable and when I need repeated references to the same data. 
Everything rest you have written you understood correctly except we do not "create" physical tables, 
this work like subqueries.

Subquery 'a' prepares data (year and today date as 'MM-DD') for further treatment, 
subquery `b` gets maximum and minimum period dates according to logic from question, 
last `select` just gathers data using these dates.

Comment: Hello Ponder Stibbons, i just added a question below , i do not know exactly how work stackoverflow. Can you please see my question below ( it is in answer part). thanks for your help

Comment: I added explanations and modification for `year` variable in bottom section of answer. You shouldn't add new answer, eventually edit your original question or ask for explanations in comments, so please delete your answer. Anyway you understood correctly how query works.